# Domino Designer 9.0.1FP3 Groovy Plugin

Tags: eclipse, groovy, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

We are using Domino Designer 9.0.1FP3 and would like to use Groovy as
   an alternative to Java.

- As far as we know Domino Designer 9.0.1FP3    corresponds to Eclipse
    3.4.2. Unfortunately we found no working    download link for an update site or archive ZIP.
- We are also unsure, if getting the Eclipse 3.4.2 Groovy plugin will suffice to get the Groovy support in Domino Designer 9 running. Any pointers on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated... :-)